# Set two fields using map

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe I want to return two fields when I use `map` in a `DropdownField`.

I have a data object `Teacher` with fields `firstname` and `lastname`. So in my `DropdownField` I want to merge these two fields and pass them to `map()`.

My current code looks like this:

```
 public function getCMSfields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
             DropdownField::create('TeacherID', 'Teacher')->setSource(Teacher::get()->map('ID', 'Firstname'))->setEmptyString('Select one')
        );

        // etc...
        return $fields;
    }
```

How is it possible to merge `firstname` and `lastname` and pass it inside `map()` and return it to the `DropdownField`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can create get functions in our custom `DataObject` to return any content that we like. These get functions can be used in lots of places, including the `map` function.

Here is how to add a `getFullName` function to return a `FullName` string in our object:

```
class Teacher extends DataObject {
    // ...

    public function getFullName() {
        return $this->FirstName . ' ' . $this->LastName;
    }
}
```

Then in our `DropdownField` we can fetch `Teacher::get()->map('ID', 'FullName')` like so:

```
public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
        DropdownField::create('TeacherID', 'Teacher')
            ->setSource(Teacher::get()->map('ID', 'FullName'))
            ->setEmptyString('Select a teacher')
    );

    return $fields;
}
```